# Apply `flipud` function to image obtained from `frame2im` in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-figure

I have a basic figure obtained from `plot()` which I converted to an image using `getframe(gcf)` and `frame2im`.

```
plot(boundary(:,2),boundary(:,1),'r','LineWidth',2);
F = getframe(gcf); 
[X, Map] = frame2im(F);
```

`imshow(X,Map)` works just fine, but when I try to apply other image related functions like `flipud` or `rot90` to `X` MATLAB says the image must be a 2D matrix.

How can I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot to Daniel and rayryeng for their help. :)

Here is what I did finally.

```
if isempty(Map)
    rgb = X;
else                       
    rgb = ind2rgb(X,Map);
end
rgb = rgb2gray(rgb);
rgb = im2bw(rgb);

rgb = flipud(rgb);
```

As said by rayryeng, this converts my image from RGB to Binary and thus is a 2D matrix I can manipulate.

Answer (score 7):

The reason why is because you have a multi-channel image.  It works for "some" images because they are most likely grayscale, and are only a 2D matrix.  Those methods won't work if you have a 3D matrix (a.k.a a multi-channel image).  If you really want to use `flipud` or `rot90`, consider using a `for` loop to iterate through each channel and flip the channels by themselves.

As such, given your image `X`, do something like this:

```
Xout = [];

for i = 1 : size(X, 3)
    Xout = cat(3, Xout, flipud(X(:,:,i))); %// or Xout = cat(3, Xout, rot90(X(:,:,i)));
end
```

`Xout` will contain your fully transformed image.

FWIW: Using `imrotate` is cleaner (à la Daniel's method).  I would recommend you use that instead.

## Aside

In your code, `getframe` and `frame2im` will return **RGB** data for your frame.  As such, your image will naturally be multi-channel :)

Comment: I took my image `X` and converted it to a binary image using `rgb2gray` and `im2bw`.
Might that work?

Comment: @KanishkaGanguly: Yes that will definitely work as it's a 2D image.  You could even do it on grayscale by `rgb2gray` and leave it at that.  However, if you want to do it for colour images, if you need to use those commands, you can't escape doing it individually for each channel.

Answer (score 0):

To rotate use `imrotate` (image processing functions begin with im), to flip a dimension use `flipdim`

Comment: But `flipud` worked for another image previously.
How can I do that using `flipdim`?

Comment: @KanishkaGanguly: Please see my post